# Advantage of org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource over oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I currently use this configuration for my projects:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
        <property name="URL" ...
         <property name="user" ...
        <property name="password" ...
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
```

And it works fine, pretty fast.
I happened to see, on an old project (spring 2.5) this configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url"...
    <property name="username" ...
    <property name="password" ...
</bean>
```

From documentation it would seem that this last option does not make use of a connection pool. I see no reason to use this configuration over mine, but it still exists so I am curious: where's the advantage/limitation?

Comment: I don't think there *is* any advantage - the docs themselves make it pretty clear that this has very limited real-life use. The limitations are that it DOESN'T use any sort of pooling, so each time you ask for a connection, a new physical connection is requested. The only possible real-life use for this would be ( as far as I can see ) if you have a single threaded program that is able to establish the connection once and make use of it through out its life time. All you'd gain is that you wouldn't have the memory footprint of establishing a connection pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st configuration is oracle specific, whereas 2nd configuration is generic. You can explicitly define driver class. 
This is the only major difference I can see in them other than connection pool support of OracleDataSource.

You can use it for generic behavior as mentioned below:

```
<bean id="baseDataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
abstract="true">
<property name="username" value="user"/>
<property name="password" value="pwd" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySqlDataSource" parent="baseDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${mySQL.driver}" />
<property name="url" value="${mySQL.url}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oracleDataSource" parent="baseDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${oracle.driver}" />
<property name="url" value="${oracle.url}"/>
</bean>
```

Property values you can externalized.

You can explore Apache Jakarta Commons DBCP which has all the features of DriverManagerDataSource
along with connection pool feature.

Comment: Would it be also possible to define that class in "driverClassName" so to mantain generic container but specific behavior?

Comment: Edited my original post. You can have a look.